# exception in I/O handler for fd3 ipython cant open ipython notebook

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

Using Ubuntu Release 12.04 (precise) 32-bit, Kernel Linux 3.8.0-44-generic, GNOME 3.4.2

ipython version 2.2.0, python version 2.7.3

nose, sphinx, jinja, tornado, pyzmq have been installed

On typing ipython notebook, the internet browser opens with /localhost:8888/tree on the address bar. But the page is not loading.

The terminal repeatedly shows 
ERROR:root:Exception in I/O handler for fd 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/ioloop.py", line 330, in start
    self._handlers[fd](fd, events)
KeyError: 3

Please help ! Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

upgrade `pyzmq` might solve this problem.

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pyzmq
```

If it doesn't solve your problem, upgrade `pandas` too.

Comment: I had this issue when I installed the msi installer for zeromq that includes pyzmq, but only for older versions of pyzmq. Older versions of pyzmq with tornado will cause this issue when you installed ioloop() and when you have a handler that is currently serving a client (web browser or REST API).